# Tshark can not parse pcap packets having special characters ^ { }

Tags: character, pcap, tshark

I'm trying to read a PCAP file, when it has username having special characters like {SRUN3} or ): \r05P^0/ 37peipei58 it's not decoding the required variables correctly.

Say i expect 15 variables as ouptput like src Ip, target IP, username, port id, .... it outputs only partial variables say 6 variables instead of 15 variables.

If there are no special characters it works perfect.

Please do advice on this.

Cheers,

Comment: There is nothing to reproduce here and you provide too few details to make it clear what your problem is. The pcap can be malformed, you might use the wrong protocol parser...

Comment: Thanks Steffen for the reply. Please note that out of 400k packets, we have only 10 packets of this kind where there is a special character for username. While others packets are parsed correctly. For those 10 packets the username got a special characters like { or ^ etc which could be the issue for Tshark to decode correctly. Is there any options to handle special characters via Tshark?

Comment: Please note that 10/ 400k packets, are of this kind having special character for username. While others are parsed correctly. For those 10 packets  { or ^ etc are part of username. Is there any options to handle  via Tshark?  Below is the packet                                                               Radius Protocol
    Code: Access-Request (1)
    Packet identifier: 0x82 (130)
    Length: 199
    Authenticator: 9e36dce15bad2eb939ceb0383aaa2e1a
    Attribute Value Pairs
        AVP: l=20 t=User-Name(1): \r05P^0/ 37peipei58
            User-Name: \r05P^0/ 37peipei58

Comment: If the user is like {SRUN3}\r\nF858484458 it output the stream in to multiple lines as /r/n is interpreted as next line. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Still - nothing here to make it easy to reproduce your problem. I you want help provide the pcap, show the way you use tshark etc.

Comment: Hi Steffen, Please can you share your email id, i will send the PCAP file..so that you can reproduce the issue i have. Thanks for offering help.

Comment: I don't publicly share my email for anti-spam purposes but you'll find contact information on my home page which is visible from my profile.